# Crystal Report Not Displyed on IIS window Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

i create ASP.NET Website using visual studio 2010 using SAP Crystal Report Everythings work fine on Viusal Studio but when i move my Site to IIS Crystal Report is Not Work and No Error MEssage is Generated

Crystal Report Version 13
Visual Studio 2010
IIS 7 on 64 bit Server 2008R2

Answer (score 0):

You Need to check:

1- Application pool .NET version it must be 4

2- From Pages and Controls >> Compilation Mode >> Always

3- Installation of the report viewer if not installed (client)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check:
1. C:\Windows\assembly
    [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y8Vy.png)
   if exist your CR Runtime installation is ok
2. Check IIS, Set "Enable 32 bit Application" to **False**
   then Test your web site, If IIS Application Pool Stopping
   follow this https://community.ipswitch.com/s/article/ka036000000Jvd1AAC/Error-503-DefaultAppPool-stopping-HipIISEngineStub-dll-failed-to-load-The-data-is-the-error

Answer (score 0):

```
In IIS 7.5 or higher version cant read **crystalreportviewer13** .so some times we need to update manually also.
and
Update your **web config** file in your web's root directory.add the following code..


<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
      <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
        <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <businessObjects>
    <crystalReports>
      <crystalReportViewer>
***<add key="UseBrowserLocale" value="true"/>
<add key="resourceURI" value="~/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13" />***
        <add key="documentView" value="weblayout" />
      </crystalReportViewer>
    </crystalReports>
  </businessObjects>
```